# When i build my app the imports become unresolved reference if they belong to another module

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, multi-module

i'm migrating an app from a single module app to a multimodule app. Im following this structure:

[Core] -> [App] -> [Feature]

I created the core module and the feature called wallet, using the File -> new -> new Module option in Android Studio and selected Android library.

In my core module i don't include any dependencies from the other modules, in my build.gradle from *app* i already included it using the following:

```
implementation project(":core")
implementation project(":wallet")
```

in my build.gradle from **wallet** which is the feature module, i included.

```
implementation project(':core')
```

And finally i can see they're in the settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':core', ':wallet'
```

```
import com.mycompany.core.data.repository.WalletRepository

class WalletUseCaseImpl(walletRepository: WalletRepository) : WalletUseCase {
    override fun getSavedOffers(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

I created a WalletUseCaseImpl which implements an interface, in the constructor i want to pass a repository let's call it *WalletRepository* when i'm typing the AndroidStudio suggest to import it. So i assume the Android Studio recognize the module dependencies.

Android Studio add this import, which is correct i can use cmd + b to go to the file and that's the file i'm using, everything is good.

This is the import:
import com.companyname.core.data.repository.WalletRepository

The problem comes when i hit build i'm getting this errors from the Kotlin Compiler:

/Users/myuser/companyprojectname/wallet/src/main/java/com/example/wallet/data/usecase/WalletUseCaseImpl.kt: (3, 24): ** Unresolved reference: data **

**Unresolved reference: OffersRepository**

**Things that i already do**: 
Invalidate Cache/Restart 
./gradlew clean 
./gradlew build

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I actually solved it, the problem was my build.gradle **(Core Module)** was missing kotlin plugin, i don't know why.

Before:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

After:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

In dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```